# I am getting this warning in React: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am seeing the above mentioned react 16.13.0 warning even after probably fixing the issue. I did go through this github issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18147 and seems like I am already calling the setState callback inside useEffect hook inside the child component. Here's the pseudo code.

```
function Parent = () => { 
  const [enablePrint, updateEnablePrint] = useState(false);

  function handlePrint() {
    updateEnablePrint(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function handlePrintViaKeyboard(e) {
      if (e.key === 'p' && (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        handlePrint();
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('keydown', handlePrintViaKeyboard, false);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handlePrintViaKeyboard);
    };
  }, []);

  function afterPrint() {
    updateEnablePrint(false);
  }

   return (
    <ChildComponent <!-- This is the line where I get the warning -->
      renderPrintComponent={props => <PrintComponent {...props} />}
      enablePrint={enablePrint}
      onAfterPrint={afterPrint}
    >
     /* some JSX */
    </ChildComponent>
  )
} 


function ChildComponent = ({
  children,
  enablePrint,
  onAfterPrint,
  renderPrintComponent
}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleAfterPrint() {
      if (onAfterPrint) onAfterPrint();
    }

    printListener.addAfterPrintListener(handleAfterPrint);

    return () => {
      printListener.removeAfterPrintListener(handleAfterPrint);
    };
  }, [onAfterPrint, printListener]);

  return (
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
  );

}
```

I even tried moving the useEffect code of ChildComponent to the Parent but still I see that warning. I'm not sure what's causing that warning to pop up. As you can see, the `afterPrint` method is being called in the useEffect hook inside the ChildComponent. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you provided a working code example or a link to a working JSFiddle. In the example above PrintComponent, printListener, and other variables are undefined.

Comment: I am aware of the undefined variables. The code is complicated and a lot is going on the components so didn't add everything. I'll try to create a working code example and add a JSFiddle link.